# termcal not creating correct dates / days

Tags: formatting, termcal

First time posting here, so hopefully I do this correctly.  This semester I teach a late start class (it is a Tuesday / Thursday class that runs from Thursday, March 12, 2015 until Tuesday, May 12, 2015)

I copied my calendar from a different class and changed it to the new schedule.  However, when I compile the new code, the dates / days do not match to what they should be.  Anyway, I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours and I'm about to pull my hair out!  Any help you could give would be awesome!!  I have tried the below code (or something like it) with more stuff filled in, or as blank as can be (like below).

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\patchcmd{\endcalendar}{[l]}{[c]}{}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcommand{\TRClass}{
\skipday % Monday (no class)
\calday[\textbf{Tuesday}]{\classday} % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[\textbf{Thursday}]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday (no class)
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{calendar}{03/10/2015}{10}
    \setlength{\calboxdepth}{0.65in}
    \TRClass
    \caltexton{1}{}
\end{calendar}


\end{document}
```

So when I run this code, it SHOULD start the calendar on Tuesday, March 10th but instead it starts it on Tuesday, March 11th.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/2693). Yes, this is just the kind of question we like: you included a working minimal example, and the problem was clearly stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `termcal` package assumes that weeks start on a Monday, so the start date of your class is always taken to be a Monday.

So in your example, although your class is only on a Tuesday/Thursday schedule, its start date should be `03/09/2014` (although I assume you probably mean 2015...).

So:

```
\begin{calendar}{03/09/2015}{10}
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Yeah at first I noticed the 2014, so I fixed that.  But you are totally correct, I am a doofus.  Thanks a bunch!  I was starting to go crazy!

Comment: @jon We've all done it :) And if you hang around a bit, all the other doofuses (doofi?) will allow you to pick up easy reputation points, if you're so inclined.